# fetch data primary key value as the index for the associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

After executing a fetch query I get a result array:

```
[row_choice] => Array
  (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [id] => 277410
        [text_value] => Two Wheel
      )
    [1] => Array
      (
        [id] => 277411
        [text_value] => Three Wheel
      )
    [2] => Array
      (
        [id] => 277412
        [text_value] => Four Wheel
      )
  )
```

How can I get a result array like this?:

```
[row_choice] => Array
  (
    [277410] => Array
      (
        [id] => 277410
        [text_value] => Two Wheel
      )
    [277411] => Array
      (
        [id] => 277411
        [text_value] => Three Wheel
      )
    [277412] => Array
      (
        [id] => 277412
        [text_value] => Four Wheel
      )
  )
```

what should I do?

My query is

```
SELECT id,text_value FROM answer_choice
```

Comment: I guess not many DB extensions provide this functionality. But if you already have the result array, you can construct the desired array yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible directly from the SQL query: but you can retrieve all your data, then re-map the array

Using PHP 5.5's [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) you can do something like:

```
$myarray['row_choice'] = array_combine(
    array_column($myarray['row_choice'], 'id'),
    $myarray['row_choice']
);
```

else for earlier versions of PHP, use [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead

```
$myarray['row_choice'] = array_combine(
    array_map(
        function($value) {
            return $value['id'];
        },
        $myarray['row_choice']
    ),
    $myarray['row_choice']
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new array variable as below.

```
$recArr = array();

while ($records = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $recArr[$records['id']] = $records;
}

var_dump($recArr);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Ha - you beat me to it. I agree if you have no other choice but to execute your query as-is, then one of the formerly suggested post-processing steps like array_combine are likely best. However in my opinion, the earlier that you can build the data structure that you want, the better (avoids extraneous memory copies and iterations) so if it's at all an option, personally I would recommend this approach. (Going to delete my duplicate answer now)